# python optimise a nested for loop with append

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have 2 for loops which would run for a large data mostly. I want to optimise this and improve the speed as much as possible.

```
source = [['row1', 'row2', 'row3'],['Product', 'Cost', 'Quantity'],['Test17', '3216', '17'], ['Test18' , '3217' , '18' ], ['Test19', '3218', '19' ], ['Test20', '3219', '20']]
```

creating a generator object

```
it = iter(source)
variables = ['row2', 'row3']
variables_indices = [1, 2]
getkey = rowgetter(*key_indices)
for row in it:
    k = getkey(row)
    for v, i in zip(variables, variables_indices):
        try:
            o = list(k)  # populate with key values initially
            o.append(v)  # add variable
            o.append(row[i]) # add value
            yield tuple(o)
        except IndexError:
            pass

def rowgetter(*indices):
    if len(indices) == 0:
        #print("STEP 7")
        return lambda row: tuple()
    elif len(indices) == 1:
        #print("STEP 7")
        # if   only one index, we cannot use itemgetter, because we want a
        # singleton sequence to be returned, but itemgetter with a single
        # argument returns the value itself, so let's define a function
        index = indices[0]
        return lambda row: (row[index],) 

    else:

        return operator.itemgetter(*indices)
```

This would return a tuple but it is taking so much time on an average 100 seconds for 100,000 rows (source has 5 rows in the example ). Can anyone help to reduce this timing please.

note : I also tried for inline loops and list comprehension which is not returning for each iteration

Comment: Please fix `source` to actually be valid python. Also what does `getkey` do? why are you using `iter` and where does `i` come from? We really need a full, working example here!

Comment: @match I have edited my question now with full example

Comment: It's still not clear what `i` is?

Comment: It is the inner fr loop index

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements are marked below, but they do not change the algorithmic complexity:

```
zipped = list(zip(variables, variables_indices))  # create once and reuse

for row in it:
    for v in zipped:
        try:
            yield (*getkey(row), v, row[i])  # avoid building list and tuple conversion 
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Comment: `yield (*k, v, row[i])` only works from python 3.5 (3.6?) and higher.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It does work in Python 3.5.  I shall leave it at that since the question is tagged `Python-3.x`

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes it is fine if it worked with python 3.5 and higher but the time is not reduced as there are still 2 for loops

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `list` out of `k` then appending 2 items then converting to `tuple` creates a lot of copies.

I'd propose an helper function with a generator to yield from `k` list then yield the remaining elements. Wrap that in a `tuple` to create a ready to use function:

```
k = [1,2,3,4]

def make_tuple(k,a,b):
    def gen(k,a,b):
        yield from k
        yield a
        yield b
    return tuple(gen(k,a,b))

result = make_tuple(k,12,14)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 14)
```

Comment: I assume i have to call this function inside the nested for loop but still the time taken is 2x of the original. I want to reduce the time

Comment: your [mcve] isn't fully runnable as-is, could you create 1 block of code which runs outside your real code so we can have a better look?

Comment: also, do you _really_ need a `tuple` ?